# Meteor client-side pagination

Tags: meteor

There's a collection `Comments`. Currently comments for the specfic `Content` are all published to the client.

Without pagination I can successfully render them in my template, insert new comments and enjoy the reactivity.

I'm fine at the moment with all comments sent to the client but I want to implement all-client-side pagination to visually simplify the page much like FB does.

Hare are the rules:

- Comments are always sorted by the creation timestamp ASC (newer at the bottom of the list)
- I need to show the total number of records in the collection (T)
- I need to show the total number of comments currently displayed (C)
- If there are more comments (C < T) I need to show a 'See more' link
- Initially I show 5 newest comments (or all of them if there're less than 5)
- New comments (pushed from the server) are instantly shown at the end of the list
- When I click the 'See more' link up to 10 extra comments (the newest from the currently invisible -- and all of them are older that those already shown) are shown in the beginning of the list

So effectively it could be like:

- have the `minTime` variable
- initially set it to the timestamp of the 5th newest comment
- when I click the link set it to the timestamp of the 10th newest comment older than the current value
- template renders all the comments not older than this value
- *at some point* calculate values C and T and save them

I tried to solve this with a bunch of `Session` variables but didn't succeed -- I think at some point getting and setting these vars from the template leads to recursion or what?
Additional problem is that I don't reliably know the 'initial' moment when I should calculate the `minTime` for the 1st time -- comments may still not be synched when the template is created or rendered for the first time.

So, the question: what is the proper way to fulfill my requirements?

Comment: obviously: how to do it so that it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
Meteor.startup(function(){
    Session.set('number_of_visible_comments', 5);
});

Template.comments = function() {
    return Comments.find({content: id_of_content}, {
        sort: {timestamp: -1}, 
        limit: Session.get('number_of_visible_comments')
    });
};

Template.total_number_of_comments = function() {
    return Comments.find({content: id_of_content}).count();
};

Template.number_of_visible_comments = function() {
    return Session.get('number_of_visible_comments').count();
};

Template.comments.events({
    'click': function() {
        var count = Session.get('number_of_visible_comments') + 10;
        Session.set('number_of_visible_comments', count);
    }
});
```

Comment: I ended doing this already, but it is not exact answer to my question. In this solution when new comment arrives the oldest of _currently visible_ comments disappears

Comment: also this code will show comments newest to oldest while we want newest at the bottom. this can be fixed by doing `.fetch()` on cursor and then `return _.sortBy` on the result, though when you return something other than cursor the whole template will be re-rendered on collection updates

Comment: to change the sort direction, just make the -1 a positive 1. to prevent the oldest comments from disappearing when new ones come in, use an $or to make it $limit _or_ timestamp comparison.

Comment: > "to change the sort direction, just make the -1 a positive 1" nope, I need _5 newest_, but show them in ASC order

> "to prevent the oldest comments from disappearing when new ones come in, use an $or to make it $limit or timestamp comparison" don't get you. is limit still 5? no matter what $or you have you still get 5 newest which means newer comments push older away

Comment: would you agree i addressed almost every aspect of your question in my answer? i see my comment above did not help you with the remaining bit, to my regret. i wonder if at this point perhaps it is time to move on from the scope undertaken, and create a new question to address the bit that remains.

Comment: unfortunately I wouldn't. the real problem was exactly how to deal with timestamp-based selection and included a number of requirements. what you wrote does only help with limits which does not conform to half of the requirements (asc order, new comments are added to the end and do not push older away). I'm going to accept your answer as the only one and doing at least _something similar_ to what I needed

Comment: ouch. do you realize how high-handed you sound? Rahul asked you to narrow the scope of your question; you dismissed him. your question has 7 'rules' - a lot to ask for _gratis_. most of the rules (draconian term btw) were red herrings apparently since now you say the 'real problem' are the only two rules i did not follow (although i contend i did do the sort as ruled, _c'est la vie_). your last sentence hardly sounds like gratitude. not that i'm fishing for compliments but who is doing whom a favor here? i don't care about points, i was trying to help you believe it or not.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime there are tow Meteor package for doing client-side pagination, one within a table. I admit I didn't go through all your requirements because of the comment exchange with ram1 above, but the package may help:

https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/reactive-table

https://github.com/alethes/meteor-pages